# How to add users to a dictionary and they don't overwrite each other in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to make so that I can just add users to the dictionary but they just overwrite each other. Have looked around but can't seem to find a solution.

```
accounts = {}


class Program():
    def __init__(self, user, username, password):
        self.user = user
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        accounts['User'] = self.user
        accounts['Username'] = self.username
        accounts['Password'] = self.password


user1 = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
user2 = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

print(accounts)
```

Output:

```
{'User': 'xxxxx', 'Username': 'xxxxx', 'Password': 'xxxxx'}
```

How do I do if I want to make both 'user1' and 'user2' appear in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like:

```
class Program():
    def __init__(self, user, username, password):
        self.user = user
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
        return "'User': {0} , 'Username': {1}, 'Password': {2}".format(self.user, self.username, self.password)
```

Then you could do something like:

```
user1 = Program(user='user1', username='username1', password='pass1')
user2 = Program(user='user2', username='username2', password='pass2')

accounts = dict()
accounts['user1'] = user1
accounts['user2'] = user2

>>> accounts
# {'user1': 'User': user1 , 'Username': username1, 'Password': pass1,
#  'user2': 'User': user2 , 'Username': username2, 'Password': pass2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to do something like this, although it's not 100% clear:

```
accounts = {}
class Program():
    def __init__(self, user, username, password):
        self.user = user
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

accounts['user1'] = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
accounts['user2'] = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

print(accounts)
```

When you instantiate the Program class, you can assign its value to a key in your accounts dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use update method.

and the key should be unique.

If user is going to be unique

```
accounts[self.user] = {self.username,self.password}
```

Now your output would be like

```
{'user1' : {'user1name':'password'}, 'user2':{'user2name':'password'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your global variable "accounts", the key value "User' is getting overwritten each time you instantiate the Program class. If you want the dictionary to hold each of the users, perhaps you can store users as a list against the key value. This is one way to achieve what you want, I think.

```
accounts={'User':[],'Username':[],'Password':[]}
class Program():
    def __init__(self, user, username, password):
        self.user = user
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        accounts['User'].append(self.user)
        accounts['Username'].append(self.username)
        accounts['Password'].append(self.password)

user1 = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
user2 = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')
print(accounts)
```

This should result in the output you want with both users and (their details) in the dictionary.

You also ask "How do I do if I want to make both 'user1' and 'user2' appear in the dictionary?" If you also want the Program instances user1 and user2 in the dictionary, you could have one key more than the three already in it, for the instances (you could call it 'user_objects') and append as before.

```
accounts={'User':[],'Username':[],'Password':[],'user_objects':[]}
....
        accounts['Password'].append(self.password)
        accounts['user_objects'].append(self)

user1 = Program('xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of data modelling, rather than Python programming. You've chosen to make your program object-oriented, which can be a good choice for this scenario. You've defined a `Program` class and you have conceived of named users that would need to use this program, with their personal username and password.

From an OO-perspective, it would then make sense to make the `User` into a class by itself and to link these users to the program (or maybe even programs) they can access.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, username, password):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User({self.name}, {self.username}, {self.password})'


class Program:
    def __init__(self, users=None):
        if users is None:
            users = []
        self.users = users

    def add_user(self, user):
        self.users.append(user)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Program({", ".join(map(str, self.users))})'


my_program = Program()
my_program.add_user(User('John Smith', 'jsmith', 'ninja'))
my_program.add_user(User('David Jones', 'djones', 'pass1234'))

print(my_program)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. Thanks for all the help really appreciate it!

```
accounts={'User':[],'Username':[],'Password':[]}

    class Program():
        def __init__(self, user, username, password):
            self.user = user
            self.username = username
            self.password = password

            accounts['User'].append(self.user)
            accounts['Username'].append(self.username)
            accounts['Password'].append(self.password)


    user1 = Program('Dante', 'Neelo', 'PassWord123')
    user2 = Program('John', 'Randddd', '123PassWord')

    print('User: ' + str(accounts['User']))
    print('Username: ' + str(accounts['Username']))
    print('Password: ' + str(accounts['Password']) + '\n')
    print(accounts)
```

Output:

```
User: ['Dante', 'John']
Username: ['Neelo', 'Randddd']
Password: ['PassWord123', '123PassWord']

{'User': ['Dante', 'John'], 'Username': ['Neelo', 'Randddd'], 'Password': ['PassWord123', '123PassWord']}
```